# Boostrap error in Electron app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron

I am try to create an Electron app using React, React-router and bootstrap. I have the following in my package.json

1. "bootstrap": "^4.1.1"
2. "jquery": "^3.3.1"
3. "popper.js": "^1.14.3"
4. "electron": "^2.0.4"

I am getting the below error, no matter where or how I call the 3 node modules this message persists. I am using the bootstrap.js file because it gives a more specific message. I have tried using the CDN files straight from the bootstrap site this to give the same error. This error is preventing my dropdown from working.

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at setTransitionEndSupport (bootstrap.js:122)
at bootstrap.js:200
at bootstrap.js:202
at bootstrap.js:9
at bootstrap.js:10**
```

Below is my HTML and my react navbar component

```js
export default class Navbar extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Render component (React component lifecycle method)
   */
  render() {
    //const { isMaximized } = this.state;
    return (
      <header >
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item active">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/iloDetails" className="nav-link" href="#">iLO Details </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Manage Servers</a>
                <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <Link to="/NewServer" className="dropdown-item">New Server<i aria-hidden="true" /></Link>
                  <Link to="/ManageIP" className="dropdown-item">IP Management<i aria-hidden="true" /></Link>
                  <Link to="/PowerActions" className="dropdown-item">Power Actions<i aria-hidden="true" /></Link>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab Manager</title>
    <link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="./assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Deploy React here  -->
    <div id="app"></div>

  </body>
  <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/popper.js/dist//umd/popper.min.js" ></script> 
  <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
  <script>
   require( "./build/renderer.js" );
  </script>
</html>
```

### Update

So just found a fix\workaround if I replace

- `<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>`

with

- `<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = 
  require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js');</script>`

then my code works, why is this the case ?? 
This has had me stumped for about 5 hours.

Comment: If you have more information to add, just edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have to load jquery.slim.min.js before bootstrap.min.css